# Show images with javascript Help needed

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I'm making a website where the user sees a text when hovering over an image. Problem is, it doesn't work on mobile devices(touchscreen etc). So I have been coding a script which will detect wether the client is desktop or mobile, if it's mobile, it will show the text over the image instantly.
But it's not really working. Can someone find my mistake?
Here's the link to the test webpage: [Link](http://studio-don.nl/ifmobile).
Code can be found in the head. (sorry i dont know how to paste it in)

Thanks!

Comment: try doing that in a media query in css, when the screen is of a mobile, copy paste the codw of hover to the  image tag, anyway its just an idea of how to do it not the actual answer

Answer (score 0):

something like bootstrap would automatically turn your hover events into click events on mobile

Another option would be to use @media queries to make them visible on mobile

```
use @media(min-width:768px){
    .textOnHover{
        visibility:visible;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than browser detection you should be using feature detection for this kind of task. Take a look at [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com) for detecting touch functionality on the client's browser. You can then use their JavaScript API to solve your problem.

If you opt for CSS class names in your Moderniser build, it will add helper classes to your `<html>` element so you'll be able to use an entirely CSS solution, like so:

```
.touch .text {
    visibility:visible;
}
```